# Program freeze after few days

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I created a little program to create a log file to record people's ID number, so far it runs good, no issues or errors, but recently I notice after running for three days it froze another program, until I force closed it. Can anyone take a look to the code to see if there is anything is wrong with it or to improve the code. Thank you.

The programs works with .NET Frameworks 3.5 and is for a Windows XP system, if is possible to make it work with a lower .NET Framework to reduce the installation of additional files.

MainWin form creates a fullscreen window to mask/cover some elements from other software. Is set as topmost to be always be on the top of everything. It has a transparent section with in a text file, then it minimize the window and finally activates a timer. When the timer finish, its maximaze the window again. It has a button to open the LoginWin form and a button to clear the data from the serieBox and return the cursor  to the textbox.

[image]

LoginWin form is a window to input login information to open the LogFileWin form.

[image]

LogFileWin form is a window to read the saved data from the text file in a richTextBox, this data is from the MainWin form. It has a close button and a button to open FolderBrowserDialog to save the text file in another location or to a removable storage device.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace LogSerie
{
    public partial class MainWin : Form
    {

        public MainWin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void MainWin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TopMost = true;
        }

        private void serieBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            this.serieBox.MaxLength = 10;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if ((serieBox.Text != ""))
                {

                    if (serieBox.Text == "WLMANTO")
                    {
                        StreamWriter B = new StreamWriter("LogfileOperator.txt", true);
                        B.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "  " + label1.Text + " " + serieBox.Text);
                        B.Close();
                        serieBox.Clear();
                        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                        timerManto.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StreamWriter A = new StreamWriter("LogfileOperator.txt", true);
                        A.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "  " + label1.Text + " " + serieBox.Text);
                        A.Close();
                        serieBox.Clear();
                        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                        timerOperador.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private void timerOperador_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            timerOperador.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void timerManto_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            timerManto.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void logButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginWin openForm = new LoginWin();
            openForm.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void borrarBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serieBox.Clear();
            serieBox.Select();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LogSerie
{
    public partial class LoginWin : Form
    {
        public LoginWin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoginWin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TopMost = true;
        }

        private void entrarBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((usuBox.Text != "") && (contraBox.Text != ""))
            {
                if ((usuBox.Text == "ADMIN") && (contraBox.Text == "PASS"))
                {
                    LogFileWin openForm = new LogFileWin();
                    openForm.TopMost = true;
                    openForm.ShowDialog();
                    usuBox.Clear();
                    contraBox.Clear();
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Incorrect", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }

        private void cancelBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace LogSerie
{
    public partial class LogFileWin : Form
    {
        public LogFileWin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LogFileWin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TopMost = true;
        }

        private void logfileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = @"C:\LogfileOperator\LogfileOperator.txt";
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path);
            string filedata = stream.ReadToEnd();
            richTextBox1.Text = filedata.ToString();
            stream.Close();
        }

        private void closeBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void usbBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = "LogfileOperator.txt";
            string sourcePath = @"C:\LogfileOperator";
            using (FolderBrowserDialog ofd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
                    sourcePath = Path.Combine(ofd.SelectedPath, fileInfo.Name);
                    File.Copy(fileName, sourcePath, true);
                    MessageBox.Show("Logfile Saved", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it froze another program"? Do those program access shared resouces that might be locked by one or the other?

Comment: If a `Dispose` method exists, ensure that you call it (ex: `StreamReader`), or use a [using statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement). The following may be helpful: [.NET Framework versions and dependencies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies) and  [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)

Comment: The following may be helpful as well: [.NET Framework 4.5 and Windows XP](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp/)

Comment: @derpirscher, the "other" stop responding, I get the close or wait dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're forced to use this old OS and old framework, you're going to have weird bugs like this. You can maybe work around it by reducing resource usage.

You're constantly creating new copies of your forms LoginWin and LogFileWin, which require OS resources. Instead create *one* instance of each form and re-use them.

There's also not any exception handling in your code, so you could have problems if files don't exist, or permissions change, or all sort of things. You need to have exception handling and that will give you more information about problems when they occur.

To re-use a form, create an instance as a private field in your class:

```cs
public partial class LoginWin : Form
{
    // store the LogFileWin form so that we can re-use it
    private LogFileWin _logFileWin;

    public LoginWin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _logFileWin = new LogFileWin(); { TopMost = true; }
    }

    private void LoginWin_Load(object s, EventArgs e) { TopMost = true; }

    private void entrarBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuBox.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(contraBox.Text))
        {
            return;
        }

        if ((usuBox.Text == "ADMIN") &&
            (contraBox.Text == "PASS"))
        {
            // add a reset function to the form
            // that makes it ready to display again
            _logFileWin.Reset();

            // show the dialog
            _logFileWin.ShowDialog();

            usuBox.Clear();
            contraBox.Clear();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Incorrect",
                            "Message",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }

    private void cancelBut_Click(object s, EventArgs e) { Close(); }
}
```

For exception handling:

```cs
public partial class LogFileWin : Form
{
    public LogFileWin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LogFileWin_Load(object s, EventArgs e) { TopMost = true; }

    // new function to reset the the dialog to be shown again
    public void Reset() { richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty; }

    private void logfileButton_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = @"C:\LogfileOperator\LogfileOperator.txt";
        try
        {
            // reading from a file can fail, so this
            // needs to be wrapped in a try catch
            using (var stream = new StreamReader(path))
            { 
                richTextBox1.Text = stream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

             var m = String.Format("Unable to read '{0}'; {1}",
                                   path, ex.Message);

             MessageBox.Show(message,
                             "File read error",
                             MessageBoxButtons.Ok,
                             MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void closeBut_Click(object s, EventArgs e) { this.Close(); }

    // we can re-use the folder browser dialog;
    // don't need to create a new one every time
    FolderBrowserDialog _ofd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    private void usbBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sourceFileName = "LogfileOperator.txt";
        var destFolder = @"C:\LogfileOperator";
        var destFileName = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (_ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                destFileName = Path.Combine(_ofd.SelectedPath, 
                                            sourceFileName);

                // every time you do anything with a 
                // file, it needs to be in a try/catch
                // in case the file doesn't exist,
                // or the user doesn't have permission.
                File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName, true);

                MessageBox.Show("Logfile Saved", 
                                "Message", 
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             // show a message to the user informing them
             // of the error and why it occurred.
             var m = string.Format("Copy '{0}' to '{1}' failed; {2}",
                                   sourceFileName,
                                   destFileName,
                                   ex.Message); 
             MessageBox.Show(m,
                             "File copy error",
                             MessageBoxButtons.Ok,
                             MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi John V, thank you for you reply, indeed I'm forced to use old OS and framework, would kind guide on how to implement your advices to re-use forms and for the exception handling.  Also external links are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, see code examples.

Comment: Thank you John, appreciate adding comments to each adjustment. One question, this section "public void Reset() { richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty; }" in the LogFileWin form, this works as the other one, to re-use the form? Thanks again.